# ADODB wait for query to complete before refreshing a different connection

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have a table in excel that is populated through a connection to an Access database. I am trying to write a macro that allows you to delete individual rows from this table. I use an ADODB connection to pass the delete command to Access, which works fine. However, at the end of the macro I want to refresh the table in excel so that, upon completion of the macro, the deleted record will no longer appear in that table.

I have already set backgroundquery = False on the connection that populates the table, but it doesn't seem to make a difference in this case. I have used the application.wait command as a workaround but I'm looking for a better solution. Is there another way to hold off the table refresh until my delete queries have run?

My code is below:

```
Sub Delete_recipe()

'Set up query
Dim Recipe_ID As Integer
    Worksheets("Recipe Adder").Calculate
    Recipe_ID = Range("New_recipe_ID").Value

'Open data connection
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Tucker\Desktop\Recipe project\MURPH.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;" _
& "Persist Security Info=False"

'Execute delete query
Cn.Execute "Delete from Recipe_master IN 'C:\Users\Tucker\Desktop\Recipe project\MURPH.accdb' where Recipe_ID =" & Recipe_ID
Cn.Execute "Delete from Recipe_ingredients IN 'C:\Users\Tucker\Desktop\Recipe project\MURPH.accdb' where Recipe_ID =" & Recipe_ID
Cn.Execute "Delete from Recipe_instructions IN 'C:\Users\Tucker\Desktop\Recipe project\MURPH.accdb' where Recipe_ID =" & Recipe_ID

'Close connection
Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing

'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:06"))
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Murph Ingredient").Refresh

'Clear data from cells
Range("New_recipe_name_merged").ClearContents
Range("Recipe_description").ClearContents
Range("New_recipe_ingredients").ClearContents
Range("New_recipe_instructions").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to execute asynchronously and wait for it to complete.
Please note that it will slow you down if you wait for each command to execute until triggering the next.

```
cn.Execute sqlString, , adAsyncExecute
Do While cn.state = adStateOpen + adStateExecuting
    ' wait for command to finish
    ' perhaps show a status here
Loop

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Murph Ingredient").Refresh
```

We have to check for a combination of states per the [State Property documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> You can use the State property to determine the current state
>   of a given object at any time. The object's State property can have a
>   combination of values. For example, if a statement is executing, this
>   property will have a combined value of adStateOpen and
>   adStateExecuting.

Further Reading:

- [Execute
  Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675023%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Option State Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think that async will be the right approach, but I'm still not quite there. When running your code, the loop didn't seem to be waiting for the previous query to finish. I printed the cn.state value right after execution began and it said the state was 5. adStateExecuting corresponds to 4 and I can't find a definition of state 5 anywhere. When I tried changing your query to "Do While cn.state = 4" it had the same issue as above and when I tried "Do While cn.state = 5" it ran through the whole code but still had the issue of not refreshing the connection

Comment: Wow. That is odd. adStateClosed = 0, adStateOpen = 1, adStateConnecting = 2, adStateExecuting = 3, adStateFetching = 8... Weird...

Comment: Ok. According to [this doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675068(v=vs.85).aspx) the `state` property can have a combination of values. Not 100% sure what that means yet though.

Comment: @Tucker I updated my answer. Please try checking for `adStateOpen + adStateExecuting`

Comment: That makes sense. I made the change and am still having issues with the refresh. I'm thinking now my issue is not with letting access execute the code in time. It works when I add breakpoints between the code and refresh, which I assumed was a time thing but maybe not. Not sure where to go next but will post if I figure it out.

Comment: @Tucker Maybe you should ask another question titled something like "Why isn't Connections.Refresh refreshing the data?" ?? I'd say to edit this question, but it feels like a useful question for future searchers. Also, with an accepted answer, it's unlikely to see any more attention from the community. Good luck! Wish I knew something more.